# Can't scroll on div inside of a another overflow div

Tags: html, css, frontend, overflow

## Behavior

I'm not able to scroll in a div inside another overflow div. The strange thing is that it only happens in mobile resolutions.

I have this HTML structure:

[image]

And these are the css rules applied to the divs:

```
  .event-chat-messages {
    margin-bottom: $event-chat-input-height;
    overflow: auto;
    height: calc(100vh - #{$event-chat-height-difference});
    position: relative;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    overscroll-behavior-y: contain;

    .event-chat-swipe-handler {
      height: 100%;
      overflow: scroll;
    }
  }
```

Refer to the following video demonstrating the issue:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1axB6ZgxyEyB9w6A_SpSqZzFsQ-yP1dm3/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure if this is what you are looking for, but here:

First I believe you need to get the `.event-chat-swipe-handler` out of `.event-chat-messages` and put it below it. Then the scrolling should work fine if the heights are given proper values. In order for vh to work in this situation, you need to surround those divs in a body and set it to a certain height, percentag, px, whatever. The second div `.event-chat-swipe-handler` won't be scrollable if the height is 100% as its parent, so change that to something more than 100% possibly:
https://jsfiddle.net/nukeboy212/Lr9dyafg/14/

```css
  .event-chat-messages {
    margin-bottom: $event-chat-input-height;
    overflow: scroll;
    height: 30vh;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    overscroll-behavior-y: contain;


  }
      .event-chat-swipe-handler {
      height: 120%;
      overflow: scroll;
    }
```

```html
<body style = "height: 100%">
<div class="event-chat-messages">
<div class ="event-chat-swipe-handler">

<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
test
<br>
test
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Note: Run the snippet in full page to work properly